# Move XML element to different node using XSLT

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation

> Below is the XML Input payload. I'm looking for an xml output should have "type" element inside the each Address node. Below is the incoming request XML

```
<rsp:response xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rsp="rsp.com/employee/Response/v30"
xmlns:res="res.com/Member/details/v1"
xmlns:resp="resp.com/details/v1">
        <res:employee>
            <resp:Employee>
                <resp:FirstName>abc</resp:FirstName>
                <resp:middleName></resp:middleName>
                <resp:details>
                    <resp:Details>
                        <resp:type>postal</resp:type>  
                        <resp:Addresses>
                            <resp:Address>
                                <resp:country>XYZ</resp:country>
                            </resp:Address>
                        </resp:Addresses>
                    </resp:Details>
                    <resp:Details>
                        <resp:type>ofc</resp:type> 
                        <resp:Addresses>
                            <resp:Address>
                                <resp:country>XYZ</resp:country>
                            </resp:Address>
                        </resp:Addresses>
                    </resp:Details>
                </resp:details>
            </resp:Employee>
        </res:employee>
```

</rsp:response>

> Here is the XSLT used and it is not giving desired output. Using this XSLT all "type" elements is reflecting in each address block.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rsp="rsp.com/employee/Response/v30"
xmlns:res="res.com/Member/details/v1"
xmlns:resp="resp.com/details/v1"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>  
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='employee']/*[local-name()='Employee']/*[local-name()='details']/*[local-name()='Details']/*[local-name()='Addresses']/*[local-name()='Address']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>            
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='employee']/*[local-name()='Employee']/*[local-name()='details']/*[local-name()='Details']/*[local-name()='type']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='employee']/*[local-name()='Employee']/*[local-name()='details']/*[local-name()='Details']/*[local-name()='type']"/>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

> Desired Output XML

```
<rsp:response
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rsp="rsp.com/employee/Response/v30"
xmlns:res="res.com/Member/details/v1"
xmlns:resp="resp.com/details/v1">
<res:employee>
    <resp:Employee>
        <resp:FirstName>abc</resp:FirstName>
        <resp:middleName/>
        <resp:details>
            <resp:Details>
                <resp:Addresses>
                    <resp:Address>
                        <resp:country>XYZ</resp:country>
                        <resp:type>postal</resp:type>
                    </resp:Address>
                </resp:Addresses>
            </resp:Details>
            <resp:Details>
                <resp:Addresses>
                    <resp:Address>
                        <resp:country>XYZ</resp:country>
                        <resp:type>ofc</resp:type>
                    </resp:Address>
                </resp:Addresses>
            </resp:Details>
        </resp:details>
    </resp:Employee>
</res:employee>
```

</rsp:response>

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. -- Note that the "XML" you have posted is not well-formed: you cannot use a prefix without a namespace declaration.

Comment: also, please share your expected result sample.

Comment: @sspsujit: Thanks for responding. I have attached the complete info including the desired output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks Michael for responding. I have provided complete xml with namespaces along with xslt.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks for the response. XSLT is working as expected.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I have similar other XML and this XSLT is not working for that XML. Could you suggest any XSLT learning links to control the xml array inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:resp="resp.com/details/v1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resp:Address">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../resp:type"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resp:type"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Re your attempt:

1. There should never be a need to use a hack like `*[local-name()='type']`;
2. You should find out what `//` means.

Comment: This XSLT is working as expected. Thanks a ton.